# Error occurs while using primefaces extension sheet:- but no tag was defined for name: sheet

Tags: jsf, primefaces-extensions

I receive the below error when I try to use primefaces extension sheet.

```
javax.portlet.faces.BridgeException: javax.faces.FacesException: /view/customer/notes.xhtml @151,47 <pe:sheet> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions, but no tag was defined for name: sheet
```

Here is the code

```
<f:view locale="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestLocale}"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:portlet="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

<pe:sheet id="sheet" value="#{treeBean.content}" var="tree"
                        height="400" showRowHeaders="true" width="700" stretchH="all"
                        movableCols="false" movableRows="false">
                        <p:ajax event="cellSelect" listener="#{treeBean.onCellEdit}" />
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Notes" />
                        </f:facet>
                         <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Comment Type" readonly="true" value="#{tree.commentType}" colWidth="150"  />  
                         <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="MTCNs" readonly="true" value="#{tree.mtcns}" colWidth="150"  />
                         <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Call Type" readonly="true" value="#{tree.callType}" colWidth="150"  />
                         <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Phone" readonly="true" value="#{tree.phone}" colWidth="150"  />
                         <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Dispute Reason" readonly="true" value="#{tree.disputeReason}" colWidth="150"  />
                         <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Placement Decision" readonly="true" value="#{tree.placementDescision}" colWidth="150"  />
                        </pe:sheet>
```

I am trying to capture the cell values using cellSelect event but getting this error while runtime. Using primeface-4.0

Comment: So your (unmentioned) version of PrimeFaces **EXTENSIONS** does not contain the `pe:sheet`. Upgrading a 6 year old PrimeFaces version would not be to bad either

Comment: Agreed with @Kukeltje the Sheet component was introduced in PrimeFaces Extensions 6.2 and higher.  You look like you are using 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer for this is to use PrimeFaces Extensions 6.2 or higher which is the version the Sheet component was introduced.